# Существует ли слово «порасспросите»?

Tags: лексика, словообразование, глаголы

Есть ли такое слово? Или только — «расспросите»?

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказано, слово ***порасспросить*** существует и присутствует в словаре.

**Схема образования**: спросить ― расспросить ― порасспросить.

Итак, у нас  **две приставки**. Значение приставки ***РАС***  понятно: расспросить ― это спросить подробно, выяснить разные стороны чего-либо.

Глагол ***порасспросить*** используется не часто и характерен для разговорной речи. Приставка ***ПО*** усиливает значение приставки РАС, но при этом она скорее обозначает длительность процесса (задать побольше вопросов в течение какого-то времени).

**Может ли приставка писаться через дефис?** С глаголами ― нет, но есть группа наречий, где она имеет дефисное написание (по-прежнему, по-русски, по-волчьи).

Answer (score 1):

Глагол "**порасспросить**" образован корректно и имеет вполне определённый смысл: **выяснить что-либо, задавая подробные вопросы разным людям**. Значение приставок можно выявить сопоставлением с более известными по смыслу словами.

Сопоставим пары, различающиеся наличием и отсутствием приставки **рас-**:

> "*спросить - скажет*"; "***рас***спросить - **рас**скажет".

Видно, что эта приставка делает сказанное *подробным*; по отношению к вопросу это может быть *настойчивость* в формулировках или *множественность* вопросов.

Сопоставим пары различающиеся наличием и отсутствием приставки **по-** (именно такие примеры употребления глагола "**поспрашивать**" приводят словари):

> *"спросить - скажет*"; "***по***спрашивай (местных, соседей) - скаж**ут** (кто)".

Здесь различие уже **не** в подробности или интенсивности *вопросов*, а в *множественности респондентов*. Соответственно, когда нужно не просто выяснить *факт* (кто или когда сделал), а узнать подробности, нужна приставка **рас-**, а при акценте на расспросы *разных людей* возникает приставка **по-**:

> "***рас***спросить - **рас**скаж**ет**"; "***порас***спросить -
>   расскаж**ут**".

Answer (score 0):

Такое слово есть (см., например, [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)). Но учтите, пожалуйста, что нет такого знака "???".